# how to improve my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sliders

i have 4 sliders on my site page .
and i use this js code to implement .
how to improve this code ?

```
$('.show1, .show2, .show3, .show4').hide();
$('.btn.slide1').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.show1').slideToggle();
   $('.btn.slide1 span').toggleClass('up');
});

$('.btn.slide2').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.show2').slideToggle();
   $('.btn.slide2 span').toggleClass('up');
});

$('.btn.slide3').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.show3').slideToggle();
   $('.btn.slide3 span').toggleClass('up');
});

$('.btn.slide4').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.show4').slideToggle();
   $('.btn.slide4 span').toggleClass('up');
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "improve"?

Comment: I guess you want to remove the copy pasted parts? Have you a plunker oder jsfiddle of you code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tilman Potthof http://jsfiddle.net/8Rtu8/1/

Answer (score 1):

use `for-loop`

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $('.show' + i).hide();
    $('.btn.slide' + i).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.show' + i).slideToggle();
        $('.btn.slide' + i + ' span').toggleClass('up');
    });
}
```

Comment: your code not working

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes you're using jQuery 1.7 or higher, and that your markup is similar to the following:

```
<div>   <!-- or some other containing element -->
    <span class="btn slide1">Slide 1</span>
    <span class="btn slide2">Slide 2</span>
    <span class="btn slide3">Slide 3</span>
    <span class="btn slide4">Slide 4</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn[class*="slide"]', function (e) {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1,    // index is 0-based, so add 1
        show = '.show' + index,         // concat index to "show" class to get ".show1", ".show2", etc.
        span = '.btn.slide' + index + ' span'; // same for span selector
    e.preventDefault();
    $(show).slideToggle();
    $(span).toggleClass('up');
});
```

If this doesn't work, please post a sample of your markup and also let us know which jQuery version you're targeting.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Rtu8/1/

Comment: @Brigadier: Changed your markup slightly. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Rtu8/2/

Comment: thanks - work correctly :)

Comment: but when I add another slide button inside show div - it does not close it http://jsfiddle.net/8Rtu8/3/

Comment: @Brigadier: Updated fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8Rtu8/4/). See comments in fiddle.

Comment: also i have 2 TYPES of buttons. button within close button and without close button. in the first case it is necessary . slidetoggle in another .slideUp/.slideDown . how to be? or add different classes to btns and use 2 blocks of code ? thx